# Debugger doesn't hit breakpoint

Tags: c++, debugging

simple code, in main (bottom of this post) there is literally one line of code, yet VS2008 marks this line as unreachable!!!
Could someone please take a look and tell me what's going on with it.
One note, if I delete the line marked as //DELETED TO WORK  in class Reader, this code miraculously works. Tried many things, pointing debugger to source code etc, etc. None of the above works.
Help needed.

Thank you.

//AClass.hpp

```
class AClass
{
    int x ;  
public:
    AClass(void);
    ~AClass(void);
};
```

//AClass.cpp

```
#include "AClass.hpp"

AClass::AClass(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    if (a++)
    {
        a = a + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        a = a -1;
    }
}

AClass::~AClass(void)
{
}
```

//Reader.hpp

```
#include <string>
#include "AClass.hpp"
class Reader
{
private:
    std::string str_;
    //Tokenizer tokenizer_;
    AClass ac_;//DELETED TO WORK
public:
    Reader(void);
    ~Reader(void);
    std::string read();
};
```

//Reader.cpp

```
#include "Reader.h"
#include <iostream>


Reader::Reader(void)
{
}

Reader::~Reader(void)
{
}

std::string Reader::read()
{

    std::getline(std::cin,str_);//read input

    return str_;//result of calculations is in str_
}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "Reader.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{


    Reader reader;
    try
    {
        reader.read();//BREAKPOINT SET ON THIS LINE IS MARKED BY VS AS UNREACHABLE!!!!!!
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cerr << "Something is wrong";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it `Reader.h` or `Reader.hpp`?

Comment: Hi, Reader.hpp would be the file. Sorry about it.

Comment: Sounds like you havent recompiled. Hover over the breakpoint (when attached), does it say "File versions do not match" or something like this? You can also force it to break, test whether it works then.

Comment: when you move mouse over disabled brake point it'll show tooltip with help. what's in this tooltip?

Comment: release or debug build?

Comment: @denis-bu the tooltip says: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

Comment: @Paranaix I did clean, recompiled, removed files (pdb, etc) from folders, cleaned and recompiled again. Nothing!

Comment: Ok so no symbols, go into the modules tab and search for your main module (usually named the same as your application), it will probably say "no symbols loaded". Rightclick on it and try whether you can manually force it to load the debug symbols. Also make sure that your in debug mode (and execute the debug exe!)

Comment: I do not know whether have you try this or not, but restarting VS/Windows + recompile may help actually :)

Comment: On modules tab see where your "Module" binary is located. Then see whether there is a <YourModuleName>.pdb near the "Module" binary. If not - then you'll need to change project settings to create it.

Comment: @Paranaix Hi, would you mind telling me how to get this module tab? Thank you.

Comment: @denis-bu it is debug build, I did recompile etc, etc ;(. No luck.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando On the bottom I have a bar with "Autos ; Locals ; Threads ; Modules ; Watch 1", if it isnt there try to find it in the menus at the top.

Comment: @Paranaix hi, thanks for reply. Yep, there is a .pdb file next to .exe. Maybe perhaps you could take this code I've pasted in OP and try it for yourself and see if the issue is on your comp too?

Comment: So, nobody knows what's going on?